# Find on beautiful soup in loop returns TypeError

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape a table on an ajax page with Beautiful Soup and print it out in table form with the TextTable library.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib2
import getpass
import cookielib
import texttable

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

...

def show_queue():
    url = 'https://www.animenfo.com/radio/nowplaying.php'
    values = {'ajax' : 'true', 'mod' : 'queue'}
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    f = opener.open(url, data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(f)
    stable = soup.find('table')
    table = texttable.Texttable()
    header = stable.findAll('th')
    header_text = []
    for th in header:
        header_append = th.find(text=True)
        header.append(header_append)
    table.header(header_text)
    rows = stable.find('tr')
    for tr in rows:
        cells = []
        cols = tr.find('td')
        for td in cols:
            cells_append = td.find(text=True)
            cells.append(cells_append)
        table.add_row(cells)
    s = table.draw
    print s

...
```

Although the URL for the HTML in question I'm trying to scrape is shown in the code, here is an example of it:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                        <th>Artist - Title</th>
            <th>Album</th>
            <th>Album Type</th>
            <th>Series</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Type of Play</th>
            <th>
                <span title="...">Time to play</span>
            </th>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td class="row1">
                <a href="..." class="songinfo">Song 1</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row1">
                <a href="..." class="album_link">Album 1</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row1">...</td>
            <td class="row1">

            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="text-align: center">
                5:43
            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: center">
                                    S.A.M.
                            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="text-align: center">
                ~0:00:00
            </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td class="row2">
                <a href="..." class="songinfo">Song2</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row2">
                <a href="..." class="album_link">Album 2</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row2">...</td>
            <td class="row2">

            </td>
            <td class="row2" style="text-align: center">
                6:16
            </td>
            <td class="row2" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: center">
                                    S.A.M.
                            </td>
            <td class="row2" style="text-align: center">
                ~0:05:43
            </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td class="row1">
                <a href="..." class="songinfo">Song 3</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row1">
                <a href="..." class="album_link">Album 3</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row1">...</td>
            <td class="row1">

            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="text-align: center">
                4:13
            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: center">
                                    S.A.M.
                            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="text-align: center">
                ~0:11:59
            </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td class="row2">
                <a href="..." class="songinfo">Song 4</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row2">
                <a href="..." class="album_link">Album 4</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row2">...</td>
            <td class="row2">

            </td>
            <td class="row2" style="text-align: center">
                5:34
            </td>
            <td class="row2" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: center">
                                    S.A.M.
                            </td>
            <td class="row2" style="text-align: center">
                ~0:16:12
            </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td class="row1"><a href="..." class="songinfo">Song 5</a>

            </td>
            <td class="row1">
                <a href="..." class="album_link">Album 5</a>
            </td>
            <td class="row1">...</td>
            <td class="row1"></td>
            <td class="row1" style="text-align: center">
                4:23
            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: center">
                                    S.A.M.
                            </td>
            <td class="row1" style="text-align: center">
                ~0:21:46
            </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
            <td style="height: 5px;">
        </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row2" style="font-style: italic; text-align: center;" colspan="5">There are x songs in the queue with a total length of x:y:z.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Whenever I try to run this script function, it aborts with `TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments` on the line `header_append = th.find(text=True)`. I'm sort of stumped, as it seems that I'm doing what is shown in code examples and it seems it should work, yet it doesn't.

In short, how do I fix the code so that there is no TypeError and what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Articles and documentation that I referred to when writing the script:

- http://segfault.in/2010/07/parsing-html-table-in-python-with-beautifulsoup/
- http://oneau.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/simple-formatted-tables-in-python-with-texttable/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation in question?

Comment: Are you sure you use the same version as in your documentation ? What I can not see in [BeautifoulSoup 4 doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) any place where text=True. They only show examples with string or compiled regexps...

Comment: I have provided the solution. It is easiest for others to understand if you show again the data that you have edited out as the error was due to the data structure and the way your code was trying to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Basic Issue

The parser is behaving correctly. You are just using the same expressions to parse different types of elements.

### Revised code

Here is a snippet, focusing only on returning scraped lists. Once you have the lists, you can format the text table easily:

```
import BeautifulSoup

def get_queue(data):
    # Args:
    #   data: string, contains the html to be scraped
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
    stable = soup.find('table')

    header = stable.findAll('th')
    headers = [ th.text for th in header ]

    cells = [ ]
    rows = stable.findAll('tr')
    for tr in rows[1:-2]:
        # Process the body of the table
        row = []
        td = tr.findAll('td')
        row.append( td[0].find('a').text )
        row.append( td[1].find('a').text )
        row.extend( [ td.text for td in td[2:] ] )
        cells.append( row )

    footer = rows[-1].find('td').text
    return headers, cells, footer
```

### Output

`headers`, `cells`, and `footer`, cells can now be fed into a `texttable` formatting function:

```
import texttable
def show_table(headers, cells, footer):
    retval = ''
    table = texttable.Texttable()
    table.header(headers)
    for cell in cells:
        table.add_row(cell)
    retval = table.draw()
    return retval + '\n' + footer

print show_table(headers, cells, footer)
```

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Artist - |  Album   |  Album   |  Series  | Duration | Type of  | Time to  |
|  Title   |          |   Type   |          |          |   Play   |   play   |
+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
| Song 1   | Album 1  | ...      |          | 5:43     | S.A.M.   | ~0:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Song2    | Album 2  | ...      |          | 6:16     | S.A.M.   | ~0:05:43 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Song 3   | Album 3  | ...      |          | 4:13     | S.A.M.   | ~0:11:59 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Song 4   | Album 4  | ...      |          | 5:34     | S.A.M.   | ~0:16:12 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Song 5   | Album 5  | ...      |          | 4:23     | S.A.M.   | ~0:21:46 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
There are x songs in the queue with a total length of x:y:z.
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution was most helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The reason you're getting the error `TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments` is because you are actually calling `find()` on a string.

#### string find

[`find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) is a python string method *that takes no keyword arguments*. Example:

```
>>> 'hello'.find('l')
2
>>> 'hello'.find('l', foo='bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

#### beautifulsoup find

beautifulsoup's [`Tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) also has a [`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method, which is what you were trying to use.

#### The bottom line

At some point in your code, you ended up calling the string find, when you wanted to be working with a Tag.

Python uses [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which can cause confusion in cases like this.

Comment: "you are actually calling find() on a string."

this is second time I have made this foolish mistake. Thank you!