# BeautifulSoup find() takes no keyword arguments error

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import sys


query_txt = input("크롤링할 내용 입력 :")


path = "C:\Temp\chromedriver_240\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.naver.com")
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id("query").send_keys(query_txt)
driver.find_element_by_id("search_btn").click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("블로그 더보기").click()

full_html = driver.page_source


soup = BeautifulSoup(full_html, 'html.parser')
content_list = soup.find('ul', id='elThumbnailResultArea')
print(content_list)
content = content_list.find('a','sh_blog_title _sp_each_url _sp_each_title' ).get_text()
print(content)


for i in content_list:   
    con = i.find('a', class_='sh_blog_title _sp_each_url _sp_each_title').get_text()
    print(con)
    print('\n')
```

i typed this code with watching online learning but in loop it always error.
con = i.find('a', class_='sh_blog_title _sp_each_url _sp_each_title').get_text()
this line show error 'find() takes no keyword arguments'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you have to use `.find_all()` to get all `<a>` tags. `.find()` only returns one tag (if there's any):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://search.naver.com/search.naver?query=tree&where=post&sm=tab_nmr&nso='
full_html = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(full_html, 'html.parser')
content_list = soup.find_all('a', class_='sh_blog_title _sp_each_url _sp_each_title' )
    
for i in content_list:
    print(i.text)
    print('\n')
```

Prints:

```
[2017/공학설계 입문] Romantic Tree


장충동/Banyan Tree Club & Spa/Club Members Restaurant


2020-06-27 Joshua Tree National Park Camping(조슈아트리...


[결혼준비/D-102] 웨딩밴드 '누니주얼리 - like a tree'


Book Club - Magic Tree House # 1 : Dinosaur Before Dark...


비밀 정원, 조슈아 트리 국립공원(Joshua Tree National Park)


그뤼너씨 TEA TREE 티트리 라인 3종리뷰


Number of Nodes in the Sub-Tree With the Same Label


태국의 100년 넘은 Giant tree


[부산 기장 카페] 오션뷰 뷰맛집카페 : 씨앤트리 sea&tree
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.find('a', attrs={"class": "<Class name>"})` instead. Reference: [Beatifulsoup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

These two links will definitely help you.

1. [Understand the Find() function in Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup)
2. [Find on beautiful soup in loop returns TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756006/find-on-beautiful-soup-in-loop-returns-typeerror)