# Getting problem while using find method in webscraping with python

Tags: python

[image]
Getting find() takes no keywords argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find on beautiful soup in loop returns TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756006/find-on-beautiful-soup-in-loop-returns-typeerror)

Comment: \[Please copy-paste code directly\]. You can use the `.find()` method for a `BeautifulSoup` object, but not for a string. Once you type `.text`, you're extracting the string from it, and that doesn't support `.find()`.

Answer (score 2):

You try to find element from String value as a .text return string. Remove .text from job_card and try again.